# Facebook get object type of http://graph.facebook.com/{id}

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I get a facebook graph object, I would like to differntiate between pages and users. 
Problem, I have not found any criteria on which I can base this decision.

A typeof function or nearly anything would be great, but I can't find anything in the documentation..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a `metadata=1` request parameter and you will get a `type` property that tells you what it is.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for! Can I give you a little bitcoin tip?

Comment: Hehehe. Not sure how! Will have to actually read the bitcoin writeups to see how I can get in on that.

Comment: goto youtipit.org and create yourself a tipit :)

Comment: Great, Is there a way to limit the return data so that it would only return the type. I don't need the other connections, fields members. (Maybe using the new fields expansions)